# Несколько React приложений на одном сервере Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Есть сервер на express и в его корневой директории есть папка static, в нем лежат несколько реакт приложений, примерно так:

```
app:
    static:
           react1
           react2
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при обращении на адрес **/react1** и **/react2** экспресс выдавал нужное приложение.

**app.js:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
app.use("/", indexRouter);
```

**index.router:**

```
router.get('/react1', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'react1', 'index.html'))
});

router.get('/react2', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'react2', 'index.html'))
});
```

При попытке перейти по данным ручкам получаю пустую страницу.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Раздавать статику в виде React-приложений можно и без ноды с экспрессом, используя только Nginx к примеру. И что значит пустую страницу? index.html отдается? Запросы получения статики работают?

Comment: Подгружается html страница с дивом 'root', в котором должно все рендериться, однако этого не происходит. 
Для меня важно это сделать именно на экспрессе, поскольку это приватные страницы, перед рендерингом которых нужно авторизоваться

Comment: Значит смотрите какие запросы из html-страницы падают и почему. Видимо скрипты как минимум не подгрузились